# Why do I have to escape the final ]

Tags: vim

I have a file containing string like this one :

```
print  $hash_xml->{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1]...
```

I want to replace `{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1]` by something else.

So I tried

```
%s/{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1]/by something else/gc
```

The strings were not found. I though I had to escape the `{`,`}`,`[` and `]`

Still string not found.

So I tried to search  a single `{` and it found them.
Then I tried to search `{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}` and it found it again.
Then  `{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1` was still found.

To find `{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1]`

I had to use `%s/{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1\]`

Why ?

vim 7.3 on Linux

Comment: The option `incsearch` (`is` for short) may be really helpful in those cases, just in case you didn't know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `[` and `]` characters are used to build the search pattern.

See `:h pattern` and use the help file `pattern.txt` to try the following experiment:

- Searching for the "[9-0]" pattern (without quotes) using `/[0-9]` will match every digit from 0 to 9 individually (see `:h \[`)
- Now, if you try `/\[0-9]` or `/[0-9\]` you will match the whole pattern: a zero, an hyphen and a nine inside square brackets. That's because when you escape one of `[` or `]` the operator `[*]` ceases to exist.

Using your search pattern, `/{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1\]` and `/{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}\[1]` should match the same pattern which is the one you want, while `/{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}[1]` matches the string `{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}1`.

Answer (score 7):

The [] are used in regular expressions to wrap a range of acceptable characters.

When both are supplied unescaped, vim is treating the search string as a regex.

So when you leave it out, or escape the final character, vim cannot interpret a single bracket in a regex context, so does a literal search (basically the best it can do given the search string).

Personally, I would escape the opening and closing square brace to ensure that the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid being caught by these special characters in regular expressions, you can try using the `very magic` flag.

E.g.:

```
:%s/\V{'div'}[1]/replacement/
```

Notice the `\V` flag at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Because the square brackets mean that vim thinks you're looking for any of the characters inside. This is known as a 'character class'. By escaping either of the square brackets it lets vim know that you're looking for the literal square string ending with '[1]'.

Ideally you should write your expression as:

`%s/{'div'}{'div'}{'div'}\[1\]/replacement string/`

to ensure that the meaning is completely clear.